# How to catch a Ctrl+ mousewheel from any place of code?

Tags: c#, events

There is a RawViewControl (I have no access to its code) that is placed on ViewDoc control - ViewDoc is a container for it. I am trying to handle  mousewheel event but RawViewControl has no such event and if I handle mousewheel event of ViewDoc it have not fires (this is right - the focus is on the RawViewControl). How could I catch this event from ViewDoc class?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: What kind of control is RawViewControl?

Comment: I have describe it - firstly I have tryed to handle mousewheel event of ViewDoc than I have tryed to catch this event on the MainWindow level - with the same result. After this I have try to override this event in child of ViewDoc and make this new class a parent for control - but there were too many other errors. Than I went to google =)

Comment: UserControl has MouseWheel event its inherited from Control.

Comment: Reniuz you are right.. But in my case there is only one event - refresh is avaliable(( Perhaps this other events are not public

Comment: Can you downcast it to UserControl?

Comment: This is great idea - really it mayght be helpfull but I have no direct access to  RawViewControl - only to some of its options

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but one way I handle any `ctrl + something` movement is, `OnKeyDown` I check to see if the key `ctrl` has been clicked. If it has I set a global variable to `g_IsCtrlDownTrue = true`. `OnKeyUp` sets it back to false.  Then, on your mouse scroll check to see if `ctrl` is down, and if it is perform your `ctrl + mouse` movement.

Comment: The problem is in catching  mouse scroll from the control that has no such public event(( or to catch this event from another control that has no focus at this time but is a container for this control without public scroll event

Comment: Yeah I realized after i wrote my reply how blatantly I misread your question lol.  Ok, just to be sure, do you already know how to create a dynamic mouse scroll event like this to your control?
this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(mousey);

Comment: Yes) I have done it - but I debugere does not come into mousey function